# How to use pow() in while loop?

Tags: c++

I need to find the highest integer x (x > 1) so that 2^x <= n (n is input from keyboard).

I wrote this but it loops forever

```
#include <cmath>

...

double x, result;
x = 2.0;
result = pow(2.0, x);

while (result <= n) {
    x++;
}
cout << x;

...
```

Comment: Your loop tests `result` and `n`, but modifies neither.   So it is an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't know how to use logarithms in C++. Im a beginner :(

Comment: No time like the present to learn! [Documentation for many forms of `log`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log) and links to still more.

Comment: In case you're confused, all this talk about the log function refers to the *mathematical* solution to this problem. No loops necessary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

must guard it to ensure correct result with test,

```
//..
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


double result, x = 1.0,
n = 8;

while ((result=pow(2.0, x)) < n)
   x++;
if (result > n) x--;

cout << x <<"\n";  // with sample n = 8 or 8.7 etc as well

3
```

Comment: Yours is the only code (so far) that gives the required result! ^^

Answer (score 4):

You need to update the value of `result` in the loop, not just once before you start the loop.

Comment: Can you show me how to update it? Im a beginner in C++. Thanks

Comment: Inside, the while loop, you need to reassign the value of `result` by re-calculating 2^x after you increment it

Comment: @HiImNghia I think what you have missed is in C++ things happen when you request they happen and in the order you request them ([mostly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule)). You cannot perform an operation, then change one of the operation's arguments and expect the result from the previous operation to be automatically recomputed. You have to perform the operation again.

Answer (score 3):

> I wrote this but it loops forever
>
> ```
> while (result <= n) {
>     x++;
> }
> ```

Here is an analogy:

You stack antique clocks into a box. You've been instructed to stop stacking when the box contains ten marshmallows. How much time will it take for you to complete that task? Answer: Infinitely long, because what you're doing does not have an effect on the condition of stopping the repetition.

Your program has the same problem: The loop repeats until `result <= n` is false. But the loop modifies neither variable, so therefore if the loop is ever entered, then it will never stop.

Answer (score 2):

Adding code to @David's answer. This is how you should update `result` in loop, so that your existing infinite loop terminates.

```
  //Assuming n is initialized somewhere else.
  double x, result;
  x = 0.0;
  result = 0.0; //Initialize Result variable first, so that while loop condition passes.
  while (result <= n)
  { 
      x++;
      result = pow(2.0, x + 1);
  }

  cout << x; // x contains exponent of 2
  //result contains next 2 raise to power greater than n
```

Moreover, Since you're calculating max power of 2 which is less than to equal to n. Another way to do same:

```
int x = log2(n);
```

Yet another way to do this via bit shifting:

```
int x;
for (x = 0; 1 << (x + 1) <= n; x++);
// Same as before  : x contains exponent of 2
```

UPDATE : Edited answer to address issue mentioned in comments. Thanks to @Adrian, I realized my silly mistake.

Comment: I type n = 100, but it printed: x = 8. Shoudn't it is 6?

Comment: @HiImNghia The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger, It allows you to execute the program at a speed the human mind can handle, not the several GHz of the typical computer these days, and see the contents of the variables. The typical use of a debugger is you step through the problematic code line by line, checking the variables and waiting for the program to do something unexpected. The unexpected is usually a bug. In your case, you step through the loop and watch the change in `result` and `x`. As soon as one or both don't match your expectations, stop and figure out why.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks! I forgot to turn it on so CodeBlocks only show the red rectangle

Comment: As with another answer, you'll need a `x -= 1` after your loop, otherwise `2^x` will ***not*** be `<= n` - as is required by OP's question.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks, but why in other answers, the 2^x is always higher than n?

Comment: @HiImNghia The problem in the two answers I've commented on is that, in each case, the loop only exits when the comparison `result <= n` is false: thus, `2^x` will be greater than `n` (= wrong).

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer!

Comment: The OP's question was "find the highest integer x (x > 1) so that 2^x <= n." Your code will return the *lowest value of x such that 2^x > n* - this is ***not*** the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205209/discussion-between-adrian-mole-and-hiimnghia).

Comment: Just a nit, depending on what the unknown `n` may be, you may need `ceil(log2(n))` to ensure proper rounding. Take `n = 9271;` for example.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think you meant `floor` instead of `ceil`, because `ceil(log2(9271))` will give 14 and 2**14 is 16384 > 9271. Moreover ceil is automatically done when it is assigned to `int`

Comment: In that case your are right, I was reading it as wanting `x == 14` as the result.

Comment: I was making exactly same mistake. Phew! Glad to see people like me.